# Why is this method to calculate the sum of a binary tree not working?

Tags: java, sum, binary-tree

I know that this code should work but it does not. Does anyone know what i am missing? I am trying to get the sum of all nodes in a binary tree.

```
public int getSum() {
    if (this == null) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return this.value + right.getSum() + left.getSum();
    }
}
```

Comment: When you state that this does not work, what happens when you try it? Do you get runtime errors? Do you get the wrong answer? What is some example input, expected result, and actual result?

Comment: How is "this" ever null?

Comment: "this" doesn't help bro.

Comment: You need to be checking for right == null and left == null, not this == null.

Comment: I am getting a null pointer exception. What do you need more?

Comment: You should be checking wether `left` or `right` are null, not `this`.

Comment: this code should NOT work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your check `this == null` is completely useless. However, you ***do*** need to be checking for the existence of your left and right nodes. Try this:

```
return this.value + (right != null ? right.getSum() : 0)
        + (left != null ? left.getSum() : 0);
```

Comment: Hey, now its working! Thank you so much! Can you just explain me why my code didn't work?

Comment: Because a binary tree node is not guaranteed to have a left and/or right child. You need to check for their existence before calling functions on them.